# Setting referenced variable inside of thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

I am having a problem with setting referenced variable inside of thread.

> Error:
> "Cannot use ref or out parameter 'output' inside an
>   anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression"

Is there any way to get this to work or achieve similar effect?

```
public static void LoadThreaded<T>(string path, ref T output)
{
    ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
    {
        output = Loader<T>(path);
    };

    new Thread(threadStart).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method returns prior to the `output` variable being set (necessarily), as the `output` is set by a different thread.

The best option here would be to use the TPL to rework this, ie:

```
Task<T> LoadThreaded<T>(string path)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew( () => Loader<T>(path) );
}
```

This allows you to start this asynchronous operation, and get the result *when it completes*, either by blocking (calling `output.Result`) or by adding a task continuation.